# Concurrent events in node and adding data to Redis queue

Tags: php, jquery, node.js, redis

I've a web application which uses PHP for serving static pages and Node.js for real-time updates. To achieve real-time updates, PHP adds data to a Redis queue and the page is updated by node using Redis queue. But in the scneario below, the data is not added to the queue and I couldn't find the reason behind it.

1- User updates a value, node receives this notification and calls `sendSomeUpdateToPHP` function inside node server.

> ```
>  client.on( 'someUpdate', function( data ) {>             
>         sendSomeUpdateToPHP(data.id, data.value);
>  });
> ```

2- `sendSomeUpdateToPHP` makes an HTTP request to PHP server (running on the same server, different port)

> ```
> function sendSomeUpdateToPHP(_id, _value){
>   $.ajax({
>         url: localhost+':'+PHP_PORT+"/someURL",
>         type: "GET",
>         data: {'id' : _id,
>               'value': _value},
>         success: function(data){
>           return false;           
>         },
>         error: function(data){
>            console.log( 'Error ' + data.responseText);
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```

3- PHP function receives the request and adds new data to Redis queue. NB. new data is added to the queue before `sendSomeUpdateToPHP()` function call is over.

```
function somePHPFunction(){
     ....
     ....
     self::$redis->lpush('elements', $return_value);
}
```

4- Finally, the loop in node is supposed to be notified as there is new item in the queue and update the client. But it simply doesn't as the data added to the queue is somehow gone/lost etc. This is all the relevant part from node server:

```
//Call this function in the very beginning and start the loop
nodeSendElements();

io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {

    client.on( 'someUpdate', function( data ) {
        sendSomeUpdate(data.id, data.value);        
    });
});

function nodeSendElements(){
    redisclient.blpop('elements', 0, function(err, data)
      {
        // send elements to everyone connected
        io.sockets.emit('elements', data[1]);

        // event loop
        process.nextTick(nodeSendElements);
      });
};
```

So in short: I'm adding new data to the queue before the previous event is finalized (`sendSomeUpdateToPHP()` function) and expecting this new data to trigger a new event in node. It is not possible or what? Then how to manage this?